# linking .s files in windows x86_64 C++

Tags: assembly, aes, x86-64, masm, masm64

I'm able to link my aes-x86_64.s in linux using gcc perfectly fine but not able to in windows using cl, or ld or gcc from TDM.

The assembly file has functions like AES_cbc_encrypt for encryption/decryption from openssl. I'm not going to be using their libraries. I am just interested in linking it. Alternatively, I converted the .s file to masm using their perl script here

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/perlasm/x86_64-xlate.pl

This perl script executes when you build openssl, it basically generates the aes-x86_64.s file which is then built into libcrypto.lib. The issue with generating a masm version is that it adds the `.notes.gnu.properties SEGMENT` which I end up deleting and compiles but my masm program just doesn't work properly when I call AES_set_encrypt_key which I believe I am calling correctly. Here is the masm program

```
.data
ks DQ 32 DUP(0)                 ; used for aes_key struct = 60 ints = 240 bytes + int rounds = 244 bytes but rounded off to 256 anyway
OPENSSL_ia32cap_P DQ 2 DUP (0)   ; unsigned int OPENSSL_ia32cap_P[4];

key db 0E0h,0E6h,00Ch,086h,0F1h,010h,0F5h,03Ah,04Eh,065h,088h,079h,074h,0B1h,04Eh,03Dh,006h,022h,09Dh,0B9h,04Eh,026h,025h,0BEh,0D1h,018h,02Bh,056h,073h,0ABh,044h,0F3h,0

.code
include aes-x86_64.asm
externdef ExitProcess:proc


main proc

    sub rsp, 28h                    ;reserve stack space for called functions
    and rsp, 0fffffffffffffff0h     ;make sure stack 16-byte aligned 


    ; AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 256, &ks);
    xor rdx, rdx
    lea r8, ks
    mov rdx, 256
    lea rcx, key
    sub rsp, 20h
    call AES_set_encrypt_key

    exit:
    sub rsp, 20h
    call ExitProcess

main endp

end
```

the script is too long to paste here but here it is: this is the converted format with the masm syntax. the original is GAS

https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/c8b99bd8

i'm not sure if this MASM syntax is correct but it compiles fine but only if i remove the very last SEGMENT part it creates which is this:

```
.text$  ENDS
".note.gnu.property"    SEGMENT

    DD  1f - 0f
    DD  4f - 1f
    DD  5
0::


DB  047h
DB  04eh
DB  055h
DB  0
1::

    DD  0c0000002h
    DD  3f - 2f
2::
    DD  3
3::

4::

".note.gnu.property"    ENDS
```

the function fails returning -1. it should return 0. I debugged with x64dbg.

Comment: There are syntax differences between assemblers ... since the incompatibility between GCC and MSVC ABIs is mostly on the C++ side, why not just assemble with `gas` and feed that object file to the MSVC linker along with your other files?

Comment: ok i did `as aes-x86_64.s -o aes-x86_64.o` after stripping all the .type, .hidden and .size directives. then removed the include file altogether of course. then tried to compile with `ml64 enc-a.asm /link aes-x86_64.o /entry:main /SUBSYSTEM:console` and here is the error 
`aes-x86_64.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol OPENSSL_ia32cap_P`

this doesnt make sense because that is just an array i am declaring in my program anyway so i'm not sure why it is an error. in a C program, it is defined as `unsigned int OPENSSL_ia32cap_P[4];`

Comment: that is defined in the aes-x86_64.s file on one line `movl OPENSSL_ia32cap_P(%rip),%r10d` so I've always just declared an array on my main file in C. I dont see how it is any different declaring it in masm the way I did it. The error does not make sense to me.

Comment: As for your linker error, try adding a `PUBLIC OPENSSL_ia32cap_P` line because otherwise it might not be visible to other modules.

Comment: That did work to compile ( was not aware of that directive at all ) but the function still fails returning -1. I believe I am calling the function correctly, unless there is something off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking has been resolved thanks to the comments posted but the code does not work because the entire GAS file is written for linux. I had assumed it was generic, but in 64-bit that can't be possible because of the calling convention. So I wanted to test if in 32-bit it would work since that code is not subject to any calling convention regardless of system since arguments are pushed on the stack.

I spent the day writing a 32-bit linux GAS program with the 32-bit aesni-x86.s file. When I saw it worked, I migrated that to windows and that worked. I could use a 32-bit program if I want but ultimately I want to code in 64-bit so I'm going to have to convert the code to MASM. I just have to write it accepting arguments in a windows calling convention.

Comment: You could just write C++ with intrinsics to get a compiler to make a loop containing AES instructions.  Like `_mm_aesdec_si128`.  Otherwise see https://agner.org/optimize/ for Agner's calling-convention guide, with suggestions for tricks like a `%ifdef` / `.if` type of thing to conditionally assemble (depending on platform) an extra instruction like `mov rcx, rdi` to adapt between x86-64 System V vs. Windows x64 calling conventions, if you don't mind wasting an instruction in one of your builds.

Answer (score 1):

The code conversion seems to have gone wrong somehow. Notice that the function `_x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_key` is marked as `\@abi-omnipotent` so it should not have the windows prologue added but in your paste we can clearly see it does:

```
_x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_key PROC PRIVATE
 mov QWORD PTR[8+rsp],rdi ;WIN64 prologue
 mov QWORD PTR[16+rsp],rsi
 mov rax,rsp
$L$SEH_begin__x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_key::
 mov rdi,rcx
 mov rsi,rdx
 mov rdx,r8
 mov rcx,r9
 mov r8,QWORD PTR[40+rsp]
 mov r9,QWORD PTR[48+rsp]
```

This piece of code incorrectly tries to move the arguments around from the windows convention to the sysv but that has already been done by the wrapper `AES_set_encrypt_key`.

Comment: I had a feeling this was not working correctly and that I could not trust that conversion so I have considered to write it all in GAS but I am more native to MASM.

Comment: there is an issue with it working on windows. i hand wrote an AT&T 64-bit linux program doing exactly as above and it worked. wrote it to a file and the bytes are exactly as they are in my C program. must be a mystery how the devs at openssl compile the GAS instructions into the crypto library on windows. the source is the same, so i guess i'll just have to dig deep because i realize most people are not this advanced i guess

Comment: if i can't find a solution for integrating GAS into MSVC, i guess i will have to manually convert 2679 lines of AT&T to MASM, probably use most of the conversion that has already been done and see where the issue is like you said about how it tries to move arguments around from the windows convention to sysv and just fix those

Comment: i found that they actually do generate a masm on windows. here is a pastebin for it. the files are not the same. i am not able to include it because of tons of errors. this stumps me because i know the libcrypto-lib-aes-x86_64.o is created from this .asm since i can see it has references for the .asm file.

https://pastebin.com/raw/ZHeYhckx

Comment: That is for nasm not masm.

Comment: I realize that so when I converted my main code to nasm, now I get this error `undefined reference to __imp_RtlVirtualUnwind'`